# SSIS 2008 Execute Package Task Connection Expression not valid

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

In SSIS 2008 I am trying to configure a package to execute another package using the Execute Package Task. In the Execute Package Task Connection expression I am using a variable that contains the absolute path to the folder where the package I want to execute is located because as we all now relative paths don't work in SSIS. The expression evaluates to what looks to be the right path as can be seen in the screenshot below.
[image]

However when I try to execute the package I get the following error that it can't find the package:

[image]

I am very confused by this because the package path is correct. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are setting the connection in the wrong place.

You need to set the connection string in the connection manager.

Example that I want to change the Package1.dtsx to execute Package2t.dtsx ..

[image]
Created Connection Manager "Package1.dtsx" that references a package in a folder called Package1.dtsx

[image]
Properties of Connection of Package1.dtsx in Connection Manager

[image]
Change ConnectionString in Connection Manager to execute Package2t.dtsx.

Comment: You would then use this edit screen and use @Vinnie 's suggestion of using the variable in the connection string

Answer (score 0):

Try including double quotes since your file path string has spaces in it

```
"\"" + @[User::RootFolder] + "\\" + "ImportSessionAndSubsessions.dtsx\""
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! I tried out your syntax but no luck--any other ideas--this is driving me crazy!

Comment: What property are you configuring?

Comment: I am configuring the Connection property

Comment: Try taking off the package name from the string.  I believe the connection refers to the file path, but there is another value for the actual package name.  Leave the trailing double quote.